# QueryException in Connection.php line 647:

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to save checkboxes. I should be able to select one or mutliple. 
At the moment I'm getting this error

> QueryException in Connection.php line 647: Array to string conversion (SQL: insert into `seo` (`url`, `meta_title`, `meta_description`, `keywords`, `robot`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (ff, ff, ff, ff, noindex, 2017-03-27 08:59:54, 2017-03-27 08:59:54))

Here is my create.blade.php

```
<div class="robots">
    {!! Form::label('noindex', 'noindex') !!}
    {!! Form::checkbox('robot[]', 'noindex') !!}

    {!! Form::label('follow', 'follow') !!}
    {!! Form::checkbox('robot[]', 'follow') !!}
</div>
```

my method in my seo controller

```
public function create()
{
    //Gets all the seo that are in the database
    $seos = Seo::with('menu')->get();
    //Lists the title of the seo
    $menu_options = Menu::pluck('title', 'id');
    return view('seo::admin.create', compact('seos'))->with('menu_options', $menu_options);
}

public function store()
{
    //Gets all the input in the fields in the form
    $input = Input::all();

    //Checks the input fields against the validation rules in the Seo model
    $validation = Validator::make($input, Seo::$rules);

    //If the validation fails the a message will pop up saying that there was validation errors
    if($validation->fails()){
        return redirect()->route('seo.create')
            ->withInput()
            ->withErrors($validation)
            ->with('message', 'There were validation errors');
    }

    //If the validation passes then it gets saved to the database
    if($validation->passes()){
        $seos = new Seo();

        //Gets the menu_id
        $menuId = (array) array_get($input, 'menu_id');
        //Saves the input to the database
        $seos->fill($input)->save();
        //Syncs the menu function in the Seo model to save the menu ID in menu_seo
        $seos->menu()->sync($menuId);

        $seos = Seo::all();
        return view('seo::admin.index', compact('seos'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've trying to save `robot` array as string. You need to serialize it first. You can do it manually:

```
$robot = json_encode($input['robot']);
```

Or you can use [array casting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting) feature:

```
protected $casts = [
    'robot' => 'array',
];
```

> The array cast type is particularly useful when working with columns that are stored as serialized JSON. For example, if your database has a JSON or TEXT field type that contains serialized JSON, adding the array cast to that attribute will automatically deserialize the attribute to a PHP array when you access it on your Eloquent model:

Comment: I'm still getting the error when I use `$robot = json_encode($input['robot']);` and `protected $casts = [
    'robot' => 'array',
];`

Comment: @Isis don't use both at the same time. If you'll still get the error, please show the error message.

Comment: I did do it separately and I got the same error as in my question. `QueryException in Connection.php line 647: Array to string conversion (SQL: insert into seo (url, meta_title, meta_description, keywords, robot, updated_at, created_at) values (ff, ff, ff, ff, noindex, 2017-03-27 08:59:54, 2017-03-27 08:59:54))`

Comment: Looks like you're using my code literally, it is just an example. Do this `$input['robot'] = json_encode($input['robot']);` before using `save()`